# 2 layouts and a popupWindow

Tags: java, android

please can someone assist, I am fairly new to android development.

I have 1 button on my mainActivity that launches a popupwindow. The popupwindow is in a separate resource layout file - and consists of a tablelayout, each button within this table layout has an image and text. The images are resized.

The popupWindow has a transparent background to allow the user to still see what is going on the background activity - mainActivity.

I have the following code however when I run it does not launch the app.

```
package mobi.blessd.user.blessd;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ScaleDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button btn_show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        if (btn_show != null) {
            btn_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_alert_dialog, null);
                    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(layout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    popup.showAsDropDown(btn_show, 20, -50);
                }
            });
        }

        //Resize elements in the table
        TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TLayout);
        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {

            View child = layout.getChildAt(i);

            if (child instanceof TableRow) {
                TableRow row = (TableRow) child;

                for (int x = 0; x < row.getChildCount(); x++) {
                    Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(x);
                    Drawable drawable = (Drawable) button.getCompoundDrawables()[1];

                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.5),
                        (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * 0.5));

                    float scaleWidth = 20;
                    float scaleHeight = 20;
                    ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

                    button.setCompoundDrawables(null, sd.getDrawable(), null, null);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I receive nullpointerexception caused by layout.getChildCount() at the following line: for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++)

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: It attempts to launch the app on my phone and then it says the app has unfortunately stopped working. I have also tested that each of the layouts run correctly separately. i.e. the tablelayout resizes correctly and the button on activitymain also works. Its only when I combine the 2 that it does not run.

Comment: Post the error when the app crashes

Comment: there is no error in android studio or in logcat, however on the actual phone (where I debug the app) when the app attempt to launch there is a dialog that appears and says "unfortunately the app has stopped working"

Comment: When it says "unfortunately the app has stopped working" you should see the error in logcat

Comment: thanks there was a filter in the android monitor, ok the error is a nullpointerexception caused by layout.getChildCount() at the following line:                    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) { -

Comment: TLayout is in the layout of the popup or in the activity layout? Its probably null

Comment: Tlayout is the layout of the popup and in a seperate layout resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
//Resize elements in the table
TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TLayout);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
...
```

should be **inside** the `onclick` method not **outside**

and you need to reference the `TableLayout` from the popup layout

change this line:

```
TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TLayout);
```

to

```
TableLayout tbLayout = (TableLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.TLayout);
```

where layout is

```
View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_alert_dialog, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have not added following intent filter for your MainActivity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

> This defines the main launcher activity for the application

Comment: hi, there is an intent filter in the manifest file - exactly the same as the one posted by yourself.